# Is there a mock way in jest to test all dynamo low-level services with my controllers?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, jestjs

I'm writing jets tests and fully support unit test for dynamo express app. Is there a good example how mocking dynamo from my controller dependencies that it returns same response and verify the type of input data at dynamoDB low level api through the following functions attributes: get, query, batchGet, batchWrite as well as which data needs to be compared. The mock structure should behave as follows: controller -> db services -> json -> wrapper and thus be able to start asserting each case.

I tried aws-sdk-mock but unsuccessfully didn't work. Below is my code snippet:

```
function getRecordIdsFromDynamo(message) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let is = message.id;
    let params = {
      Key: { id:  id },
      TableName: LOOKUP,
      ConsistentRead: true,
      ProjectionExpression: 'activeRecord'
    }

    dynamoClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
      try {
        let activeRecords = [];

        if(data.Item.activeRecord)
          activeRecords = data.Item.activeRecord.values;
        resolve(activeRecords);
      } catch(){}
    })
  })
}

function getRecordsFromDynamo(keys, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let results = [];
    let params = { RequestItems: {} };

    if(keys.length == 0)
      return resolve(results);

    // unprocessed logic...

    dynamoClient.batchGet(params, function(err, data) {

      // err logic...

      const responses = data.Responses[RECORD],
        newUnprocessedKeys = data.UnprocessedKeys[RECORD];
      results = results.concat(responses);
      resolve(results)
    })
  })
}

exports.getRecords = function(message) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getRecordsIdsFromDynamo(message)
      .then((records) => {
        let keys = records.map((id) => {
          return { RecordId: id }
        });
        getRecordsFromDynamo(keys, message.id)
          .then((records) => {})
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}

// test code
exports.getActiveRecordIds = async (message, docClient) => {
  let data = await getActiveRecordsIdsfromDB(message, docClient);
  console.log("data.Items =========>", data.Items);
  return {
    "Items": {
      activeRecordIds: {
        values: data.Items
      }
    }
  }
};

/**
 * 
 * @param {String} messageDevice
 * @param {AWS} docClient
 * @returns {Promise<object>} return promise with activeRuleIds
 */
function getActiveRecordsIdsfromDB(message, docClient) {
  const activeRecords = db.getRecords(message);
  console.log("In getActiveRecordsIdsFromDB " + activeRecords);

  const params = {
    Key: { id:  message.id },
    TableName: LOOKUP,
    ConsistentRead: true,
    ProjectionExpression: 'activeRecordIds'
  };

  return docClient.get(params).promise();

};

beforeEach(() => {
    // Clear all instances and calls to constructor and all methods:
    Message.mockClear();

    event = record.event;
    recordId = record.id;
    ts = record.ts;
    context = '1357';

    message = new Message({
      id: id,
      ts: ts,
      event: event
    }, context);
  });

  it('should get all active records from dynamo', () => {

    AWS_mock.mock('DynamoDB.DocumentClient', 'get', function(params, callback) {
      callback(null, { Items: ['1234', '4321'] });
    });

    let docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    return getActiveRecordsIds(message, docClient)
      .then(recordIds => {
          expect(recordIds).toEqual({ Items: { activeRecordsIds: { values: ['1234', '4321'] } } });
        });
  });
```

Comment: try bringing up local dynamodb.

Comment: hey @bestwishes are you suggest use serverless-dynamo-local plugin?

Comment: yes. if mock does not work as expected.

Comment: the problem I'm not using serverless but express middleware and could @bestwishes you pls post quick jest solution to test essentially the local dynamo?

Comment: Is aws localstack an option to run local services in aws, which be better approach?